# How to specify "##" at beginning of line in autohotkey script?

Tags: autohotkey

I have this script:

```
:r0*:vidrevph::
(
[[
##intro
- 
]]
)
```

but when it runs, it leaves out the **##**:

```
[[
intro
-
]]
```

**How can I make it include the ##?**

Comment: What're all these scripts for, anyway, if you don't mind me asking? :P

Comment: I use them in sites made with my php framework which has a simple batch syntax to type multiple records in a text file then dump them into your site, here's a video explaining it:http://www.tanguay.info/datapod/index.php?pg=videos&id=2

Comment: That's really very cool, good luck with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#` is autohotkey's modifier for your windows key. That's (I believe) hitting Windows key and #!

Try `{#}{#}intro` instead.